# Is Multi level partitioning possible in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, partition

I have a table with 7 columns in it. Table consist of 30 millon records. I already did range partition on date column. Now I want to further create sub-partition or partition by partition. I'm thinking to create list subpartition.

Is that possible to create sub-partition in SQL Server?

Is the below partition table  is valid one.is this doing similar to multi-level partitioning

```
CREATE TABLE log
( 
    USER_ID INT, 
    R_ID INT , 
    IP_ADDRESS VARCHAR(255), 
    ACCESS_TIME DATETIME, 
    H_ID INT --range 1-5 
    -- ... few more columns. 
    PRIMARY KEY(USER_ID,ACCESS_TIME) 
)ON AccessTimePartitionScheme(ACCESS_TIME); 

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_log_H_ID 
    ON log (H_ID) 
    ON SubPartitionSchemeH_D (H_ID); 

CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION SubPartitionFunctionH_ID (INT) AS 
    RANGE LEFT FOR VALUES (1, 2, 3, 4, 5); 

CREATE PARTITION SCHEME SubPartitionSchemeH_ID AS 
    PARTITION SubPartitionFunctionH_ID ALL 
    TO ([PRIMARY]);
```

Comment: Why do you want to de-partition the data even further? Partitioning is not a performance feature, but rather a management one. I don't think you can create a partition from a partition, but you can create an original partition which is split on many levels once

Comment: @siggemannen i have a usecase that under each partition approx 3M records present.i don't want to scan entire 3M records.In my query i have another column which can even split futher.so if i perform list partitioning on that column the query excution time and resource consumption will be very less compare to now.

Comment: if your Clustered index is PartitionColumn, SecondPotentialPartitionColumn it won't scan anyway but just lookup stuff. As i said, partitioning won't beat a regular Index in performance, what it's useful for is ability to put different partitions on different drives, switching data in / out without physical data movement, not pure SELECT speed

Comment: There is no sub-partition or multi-level partitioning in SQL Server as @siggemannen mentioned. If you have a composite clustered index on the date and list value, only rows for the specified date/list value will be touched, no need to partition on both columns. Queries need to specify both date and list value.

Comment: Out of curiosity why are you partitioning anyway? Unless you have a specific use-case for a skip-scan, you won't get any query performance benefit, it's just a management option.

Comment: CREATE TABLE log (
    USER_ID INT,
    R_ID INT ,
    IP_ADDRESS VARCHAR(255),
    ACCESS_TIME DATETIME,
    H_ID INT  --range 1-5
    -- ... few more columns.
    PRIMARY KEY(USER_ID,ACCESS_TIME)
)ON AccessTimePartitionScheme(ACCESS_TIME);

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_log_H_ID ON log (H_ID) ON SubPartitionSchemeH_D (H_ID);

CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION SubPartitionFunctionH_ID (INT)
AS RANGE LEFT FOR VALUES (1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

CREATE PARTITION SCHEME SubPartitionSchemeH_ID
AS PARTITION SubPartitionFunctionH_ID
ALL TO ([PRIMARY]);
what's you're thoughts on above table

Comment: @ArunPrasanth partitions don't improve performance, they can actually harm it unless you're very careful. They're a data management feature, making it easier to move chunks from one table to the other, to different files or drop them. So, as everyone else already asked, *why do you use partitioning?*

Comment: 3M rows isn't a lot either. 30M is a bit, but not that much. In a columnstore index 1M rows is the size of the deltastore, the "temporary" bucket holding rows before they get compressed in columnstore buckets. What queries are run against this table? I suspect the feature you really need is columnstore indexes, not partitions